# Form Combobox populate from table based filtered by record

Tags: ms-access

I have tried to make a combobox in a form that populates from a table which contains names where the IDfile field is the connection. I have tried the above mentioned formula in the combobox, but I receive an error that IDfile could refer to more than one table. Thank you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Names], IDfile FROM [Names], Dosare WHERE ((([Names].IDfile)=[Files].[IDfile]));
```

Comment: I think table names in FROM don't correspond to table name in WHERE. The error means that you have to specify full column name, including table name

Comment: _[Fles].[IDfile]_ indicates that _Fles_ is a table name, yet it is not in the list of tables in the `FROM` clause. As for the error: in this case you should indicate `SELECT` clause, table whom `IDfile`belongs to ([YourTableName].[IDfile]).

Comment: You are querying the tables `[Names]` and `Dosare`, both seem to contain a field named `IDfile`. Also, your WHERE clause refers to an additional table `[Files]` which is unknown (because it's not part of the FROM clause). Open the rowsource in query editor and fix the issues there.